# Sorting Slick query results in a for expression

Tags: scala, scalaquery, slick

The following function works fine, but I would like it to sort the results first by parent_id, and then by order.

```
def getTree = for {
  (a, c) <- Activities leftJoin Clients on (_.id === _.id_a)
} yield (a.id, a.label, a.parent_id, a.order, c.id.?, a=c.name)
```

How do I do that using Slick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like with ordinary collection ?

```
getTree.sortBy(r => r._3 ~ r._4)
```

Comment: How intuitive the tuple syntax is...not. Too bad old orderBy(nameThatHasMeaning, otherMeaningfulName.desc) has been  deprecated in favor of sortBy(x=> x._3 ~ x._4) syntax. Slick author had a reason for doing so, but end users suffer boilerplate and pointless counting out which tuple number as a result.

Comment: You could `yield` some case class instance, and `getTree.sortBy(r => r.parent_id ~ r.order)`, but actual declaration of case class is a boilerplate. Maybe named `Tuple`-s, with constructor like `('name1 -> value1, 'name2 -> value2)` and accessor like `apply(name: Symbol)` will be useful in core Scala? For example: `yield (a.id, a.label, 'parent_id -> a.parent_id, 'order -> a.order, c.id.?, a=c.name)`, then `getTree.sortBy(r => r('parent_id) ~ r('order))`

Comment: Is this answer still valid for Slick 2.1? IDEA is not finding the ~ operator. Or am I missing some magic import statement?

Answer (score 2):

With Slick 2.1, I found this to work:

```
myQuery.sortBy(r => (r._3, r._4))
```

(verified by calling `selectStatement` on my query)